# I want to pop up a drop down list on press of @.

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

i am new to android and trying to make a tagging feature in which when i type @ a drop down list will be shown(not after writing letter after @).. I read the similar type of question here but i did not get the answer.. Please help me with this problem .

```
  MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    mt.setTokenizer(new AtTokenizer());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);

    mt.setThreshold(1);
    mt.setAdapter(adp);

    }
public class AtTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {

        int i = cursor;
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@')
            i--;
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ')
            i++;
        return i;

    }


    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {

        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();
            while (i < len) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == '@') {
                    return i;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        return len;
    }


    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();

        while (i > 0  && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
            i--;
        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i-1) == '@') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            }
            else {
                return text;
            }
        }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I google'd while and i get the solution. I do code as below and its work for me.I just setup the auto-complete in our Activity onCreate() method.

In my case, i am using the `@` character to identify the start of pieces of text that should be lookedup and spaces to determine the end of the look up token.

```
public class MultiAutoCompleteTextViewDemo extends AppCompatActivity
{
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView inputEditText;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        inputEditText = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
        inputEditText.setTokenizer(new UsernameTokenizer());
        inputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int cursor = start;
                if (cursor >= s.length()) cursor = s.length()-1;
                if (isValidToken(s, cursor)){
                    String token = getToken(s, start);
                    new LinkedinSkillAsyncTask((Activity) getApplicationContext()).execute( token );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isValidToken(CharSequence text, int cursor){
        for (int i=cursor; i>=0; i--){
            if (text.charAt(i) == '@') return true;
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String getToken(CharSequence text, int cursor){
        int start=findTokenStart(text, cursor);
        int end=findTokenEnd(text, cursor);
        return text.subSequence(start, end).toString();
    }

    private int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') { i--; }
        return i;
    }

    private int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();
        while (i < len && text.charAt(i) != ' ' && text.charAt(i) != ',' && text.charAt(i) != '.'  ) {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public class UsernameTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

        @Override public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
            int i = text.length();
            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') { i--; }
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(), Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text + " ";
            }
        }

        @Override public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;
            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
                i--;
            }

            if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
                return cursor;
            }

            return i;
        }

        @Override public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;
            int len = text.length();
            while (i < len) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    return i;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return len;
        }

    }

    public class LinkedinSkillAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private Activity context;
        public String data;
        public List<String> suggest;
        public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;

        public LinkedinSkillAsyncTask(Activity cntxt) {
            context = cntxt;
        }


        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
            String newText = key[0];
            newText = newText.trim();
            newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
            try {
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("http://www.linkedin.com/ta/skill?query="+newText);

                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
                suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("resultList");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("displayName");
                    suggest.add(SuggestKey);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }

            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MultiAutoCompleteTextView inputEditText = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) context.findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
                    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggest);
                    inputEditText.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

For More detail you can [read this tutorial](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/04/building-twitter-style-autocomplete-for.html). For example check this [GitHub](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) demo project.